# How can I set the onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse property of FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement local push notifications using flutter_local_notification, and I want to perform certain actions when FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show is called while the Flutter app is in the background. I found that the onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse property of FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize is the part where such actions should be written. However, even if I write code like the following, it doesn't seem to be executed.

How can I trigger onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse? I would be incredibly grateful if someone who knows could provide some advice.

I assume you are referring to an Android device.
Also, even when running the following sample code, the debugPrint is not being executed.

```dart
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (notificationResponse) async {
        debugPrint('[onDidReceiveNotificationResponse]');
        if (notificationResponse.payload != null) {
          debugPrint('notification payload: ${notificationResponse.payload}');
        }
      },
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: notificationTapBackground,
    );
```

```dart
/* top-level */
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void notificationTapBackground(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
  debugPrint('[notificationTapBackground()]');
}
```

-version-

Flutter: 3.10.6
flutter_local_notification: ^14.1.0

Answer (score 1):

for firebase notification

- FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen will run when you receive a notification.
- FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage() will run when you tap the notification while the app is still in the background.
- FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen will run when you tap the notification when the app is being terminated.

for local notification

- onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse will run when you tap the notification while the app is in the background or terminated.
- onDidReceiveNotificationResponse will run when you tap the notification while the app is in the foreground.
- for your problem, you need tap to notification to run debugPrint

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I understand each property, and among them, `onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse` may be a property to fulfill what I want to do, so I implemented it, but it will be executed even if I tap the notification tab. (`debugPrint` in the sample code) is not executed, so I asked the question